# New table not showing up in publication's article list in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I'm very new to SQL Server. I just had someone transfer my entire database from Access to SQL Server and I'm trying to get up to speed.

This is a merge replicated database.

I added a new table "EmailList" to the database "CRM", then went to the "CRM" Publisher properties in SMSS and noticed that when I expand the article list, my new table is not there for me to specify as an object to publish.

I need this new table to be replicated to all subscribers. How do I get it to show in the article list so that I can check it and have it replicate? I tried creating a new snapshot, but that didn't work.

Also, I've been (unsuccessfully) reading about ways to do this, and I get the impression I might have to have the publisher put a new snapshot on all the subscribers' systems to do this.  That would be awful as I have several subscribers who are often out of synch and I don't want to wipe out their data when they do finally synch.  Do I have to wait until everyone synchs, then have everyone stop making changes, then make my schema changes, and then have them replicate again?  This would be horrible, please say I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, did you uncheck the "Show only checked articles in the list" box when viewing the Articles tab of the publication properties?

[image]

Comment: I didn't even notice that checkbox!  Thank you so much, that was the problem.  :)  I'm more novice than I imagined.